# How is an RPG class hierarchy to be used?

Tags: class

I would like to make an RPG in the object oriented programming style. I have experience with oo programming, but have never worked with large groups of classes and subclasses. I am starting with this
http://members.gamedev.net/emmanuel_deloget/
and creating my own structure similar to it. The problem is I don't understand how the structure is to be used. Do you create static classes for things like races and use those, or do you create an object from the single race class? it is confusing to me because I would assume you  create a single race class and when the 'Main' class initializes you create all of the individual classes, but the above chart does not show any methods for initializing these objects with the exception of the constructor. But because races will have different member variable values, how would I use the above chart to initialize a race object? Or is this chart incomplete? (if its incomplete, then that is what has been confusing me I think)

Comment: This question is much too broad to be answered.

Comment: The question comes down to whether you use static classes, or whether you create objects from those classes, and whether a chart like this is incomplete. Is that still too broad?

Comment: I found this guide really useful when implementing my RPG system:
http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-composite-design-pattern-for-an-rpg-attributes-system--gamedev-243 As the title states, it is a composite design for an RPG attribute system. The example code is written in ActionScript 3.0, but it is easy to understand and can easily be translated into any other Object Oriented Programming language, without having any knowledge in AC3.

Answer (score 3):

Strong suggestion: **Don't use an inheritance hierarchy** for representing objects in an RPG.

Use **composition** instead, and use [prototype-based programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) objects for defining object attributes and behaviours.

The simple reason is that it is impossible to represent the behaviours of a complex RPG in a inheritance-style class hierarchy.

As an example, suppose you have a iron golem as a monster in your game. It needs to have:

- The properties of the "iron" material in relation to what is able to cause damage (i.e. very resistant to impact, very resistant to fire, very vulnerable to rust or acid)
- The properties of a "large humanoid" with respect to combat and actions (cannot fly, can walk, can be decapitated, can wield oversized weapons and armour)
- The properties of a "artificial construct" for magic effects (invulnerable to fear, not living, magically animated)
- The properties of a "semi-intelligent monster" with repect to AI and behaviour (hostile to player, attacks player on sight, etc.)

All of these kind of properties could theoretically be mixed and matched. So you will never be able to define a simple inheritance heirarchy that contains them all. Don't even try, just make your iron golem a composite of the relevant properties.

I speak from experience of implementing RPG object models - if you are interested take a look at the source code for [Tyrant](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tyrant/) (a roguelike game I wrote many years ago). I started with an inheritance hierarchy but eventually had to refactor the entire code base to a prototype-based model.